# replace zeros and trim spaces regex pattern not seem to be working as expected in elasticsearch analyzer

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

Basically I would like my index/search analyzer to remove certain characters.
I don't want leading 0s nor any leading or trailing spaces. Below is the char filter I've defined. Notice the pattern I'm attempting. I'm no regex expert but I was expecting this to work.

```
    "char_filter" : {
        "replace_zeros_pattern" : {
            "type" : "pattern_replace",
            "pattern" : "^0*|\s",
            "replacement" : ""
        }
    },
```

But elastic is giving the following exception:

> {"error":"ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse source for create >index]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized character escape 's' (code >115)\n at [Source: [B@461feff0; line: 1, column: 318]]; ","status":400}

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a site that I've personally found to be super helpful in constructing regex patterns.  it helps a lot for learning as you go, and lets you test out the pattern on sample text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double-backslash your "s".  The string literal `"\\s"` will result in "\s" being stored in the string, which is what you want.

That should resolve the error.  After that, I think the pattern you want is actually `"^\\s*0*|\\s*$"`  That pattern (when applied globally) will remove zero or more spaces followed by zero or more "zeros" at the beginning of the string, as well as any spaces that appear at the end of the string.

Your pattern does not work because `^0*|\s` means "Look for `0*` at the beginning of the string, and if that doesn't work, then look for `\s` anywhere in the string".  The problem is, `0*` does succeed - it just matches zero characters (since * means zero or more).  So it does not move on to try and look for any spaces.  The | is an exclusive or in this case.  Now you could try `^(0|\\s)*`.  That would look at the beginning of the string for a zero or space, and keep doing that over and over again until it couldn't find any more.  However, that would also match things like '0 0 0 1234', which is probably not really what you want.

Note that in my pattern I also use the |, which means that it will either match `^\s*0*` or the `\s*$`.  This is why it needs to be applied globally in order to make sure you trim leading zeros and spaces AND trailing spaces.

Comment: could you elaborate on your pattern. Why the one I proposed doesn't work and your `"^\\s*0*|\\s*$"` does?

Comment: @HorseVoice sure thing - I edited my answer with some additional details.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. But in your example, you are also using a pipe. Would that also be an OR? I'm a bit confused about making both of these conditions apply